# PHP for loop dates

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop where I specify a beginning date and end date and I want to pull a random mix of dates where each date will always be later than it predecessor and earlier than the next number.

There is no pre-defined set of dates I need, I may have 10 - I may have 100 or 1000 as long as they exist within the start and end dates.

Example:

```
2015-01-15 08:06:00
2015-01-15 15:23:42
2015-01-16 06:03:00
.........
.........
2015-01-20 08:18:32
```

This is what I have (which is wrong):

```
$start = strtotime('2015-01-10 08:00:00');
$end = strtotime('2015-01-20 10:57:59');

for ($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++) {

  //Current time + Anywhere between 1 hour and 3 days
   $x = $i + (int)rand(3600,259200);  

   echo "<p>" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $x) . "</p>";       
}
```

In my tests, I'm not getting any results...I believe the loop is running infinitely...or something else is wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your logic seems flawed.  What happens if you add a random amount of time to the current date sequence that takes you past the end date but still less than the number of dates you want to generate?  What it seems you need to be doing is looking at time between the start and end dates and the number of iterations to determine an average date interval between dates, then introduce a jitter to randomize +- some amount of time to that average.  You would then need to take a look at the remaining time left to the end and recalculate with each iteration.

Comment: Your varibale `$end` is equal to 1421769479 :), which is such a huge number

Comment: @smarber but `$start` is also a huge number, with about 1 million smaller than `$end`

Comment: The number of loops is about 865k. It's a big number of iterations that takes some time to complete (a dozen of seconds, I guess) and produces about 24 MiB of output. It's not about it not ending to run, it's the browser that is not optimized to crunch and render documents so big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I gather your question correctly, it seems like you're going about it the wrong way. The easiest way would be to generate random times in a range (between `$start` and `$end`) and then sort them. That way you don't have to guess at how much time-space you have left when choosing a random interval.

```
$start = strtotime('2015-01-10 08:00:00');
$end = strtotime('2015-01-20 10:57:59');


$num_randoms = 10;

for ($i=0;$i<$num_randoms;$i++) {

   $dates []= (int)rand($start,$end);  

}

sort($dates);
foreach ($dates as $x) {

   echo "<p>" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $x) . "</p>";       

}
```

Comment: You are just making your code more complicated by introducing the need of having to sort.

Comment: @ultrajohn but working. How would you have a sorted result without sorting?

Comment: @martti please check my suggested answer above.

Comment: @ultrajohn that will give a different result, random in each equal spaced time segment (your answer) vs random between start and end (amphetmachine). It's not really clear what OP wants to acquire.

Comment: @martti this has made me curious so I asked about it in stat.se.com http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134241/generation-of-random-number-from-an-interval/134245#134245

Answer (score 0):

You assumed that those two will be your dates

```
$start = strtotime('2015-01-10 08:00:00');
$end = strtotime('2015-01-20 10:57:59');
```

You assumed also that you will use specific range of seconds for pseudorandom number generation

```
$min = 3600; // 1 hour
$max = 259200; // 72 hours (3 days)
```

The first step you need to do is to reduce the ending number of seconds with the range maximum. This will assure you that latter date will be before the specified date

```
$end -= $max;
```

And at the end here is the proper loop. I used `while` loop because it is more readable.

```
while ($start < $end) {
    $start += (int) mt_rand($min, $max); // add the generated value to the start seconds
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
}
```

PS. Notice I used the [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function

Comment: This seems much better than a for loop, but I can't get this to work. It shows up blank.

Answer (score -1):

Use the milliseconds representation of you date value. Pseudo-code is as follows:

1. Convert the start date to its milliseconds representation `sm`
2. Convert the end date to its milliseconds representation `em`
3. For i = 0 up to n, `n` is the number of dates...
   3.1 randomize some value between `sm` and `sm + offset`
   3.2 convert the generated value to its date object representation

   3.3 assign `sm = sm + offset` and check if `sm < em`

   `offset` is the size of the sampling interval, `offset <= (em - sm) / n`

Comment: Multiple problems with this solution: 1) Dates are too evenly distributed in the range; 2) If `offset == (em-sm)/n` it will generate `n-1` dates. [jsfiddle showing distribution graph](http://jsfiddle.net/wmu640rc/1/)

Comment: By contrast, [here is a jsfiddle with a truly random distribution curve](http://jsfiddle.net/kcskrqpa/).